# How can I create phone signup user flow without verification?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-ad-b2c

I want to create Azure AD B2C Signup flow that accepts a phone number and password. I don't want to enforce phone number verification.
I also want to create a login flow that accepts the phone number and password.
Please how can I create these kind of signup and login user flows?

I have tried to modify the existing user flows, but it seems there is no way to remove the phone number verification.
I have been looking at the Identity Experience Framework and I can't find a documentation for phone signup or login using Identity Experience Framework.

Comment: According to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-sign-up-and-sign-in-policy?pivots=b2c-user-flow#create-a-sign-up-and-sign-in-user-flow), it allows you to create sign-up flow with other options. `Under Local accounts, select one of the following: Email signup, User ID signup, Phone signup, Phone/Email signup, or None`

Comment: @TinyWang these creates the default user flows with verifications steps, for example, phone signup does not allow one to provide a password. I want a phone signup with just phone and password, I want to do the verification in another step within my app.

Comment: sorry for misunderstood

Answer (score 0):

For phone signup and signin using Identity Experience framework you can refer https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/signup-signin-with-phone-number

There is no direct way to skip the phone verification step. However, you can bypass the SMS code for a specific phone as mentioned [here](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/catering-for-testing-and-automating-when-you-use-phone-login-with-otp-with-azure-ad-b2c-a315af446888).